# Terraform .tfvars cast decoding error

Tags: validation, syntax, terraform

I'm trying to set up something really simple with Terraform, but it gives me an error I haven't seen before.

When I run `terraform validate -var-file=secrets.tfvars` I get the following error:

```
Error loading files open /home/MYUSER/Documents/git/packer-with-terraform/terratest/-var-file=secrets.tfvars: no such file or directory
```

And when I run `terraform plan -var-file=secrets.tfvars` I get this:

```
invalid value "secrets.tfvars" for flag -var-file: Error decoding Terraform vars file: At 1:10: root.variable: unknown type for string *ast.ObjectList
```

I have three files within the same folder, and their content is minimal:

#### providers.tf

```
provider "aws" {
    region                      = "us-west-1"
    access_key                  = "${var.access_key}"
    secret_key                  = "${var.secret_key}"
}
```

#### main.tf

```
resource "aws_instance" "master_proxy" {
    ami                         = "ami-123sample"
    instance_type               = "t2.micro"
}
```

#### secrets.tfvars

```
variable "access_key" { default = "sampleaccesskey" }
variable "secret_key" { default = "samplesecretkey" }
```

If I set `access_key` and `secret_key` directly, and not via variables, then it works. A similar setup with secrets-files and whatnot works on another project of mine; I just don't understand what's wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `terraform validate` validates a folder of `.tf` files to check that the syntax is correct. You can't pass a separate vars file to the command. In fact, `terraform validate` won't even check your variables are even set properly.

Secondly, your `secrets.tfvars` file is using the wrong syntax. Instead you want it to look more like this:

#### secrets.tfvars:

```
access_key = "sampleaccesskey"
secret_key = "samplesecretkey"
```

But this will error because you haven't actually *defined* the variables in a `.tf` file:

#### providers.tf

```
variable "access_key" { default = "sampleaccesskey" }
variable "secret_key" { default = "samplesecretkey" }

provider "aws" {
    region                      = "us-west-1"
    access_key                  = "${var.access_key}"
    secret_key                  = "${var.secret_key}"
}
```

If you don't have a sensible default for a variable (such as typically in this case) then you can remove the `default` argument to the variable and this will make Terraform error on the plan because a required variable is not set:

#### providers.tf

```
variable "access_key" {}
variable "secret_key" {}

provider "aws" {
    region                      = "us-west-1"
    access_key                  = "${var.access_key}"
    secret_key                  = "${var.secret_key}"
}
```

Comment: I just answered my own question, but your answer provides a much more thorough explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I messed up big time. I somehow managed to forget the supposed structure (and difference) of `*.tf` and `*.tfvars` files.

For those who might run into a similar problem later on:

- `*.tf` files are for **configuration** and **declaration**, which means that any `variable`s must be defined within a `*.tf` file.
- `*.tfvars` files are for **giving values to already defined variables**. These files can be passed with the `-var-file` flag (which I had misused).

Answer (score 0):

```
     # Set a Provider
    provider "aws" {
      region     = "${var.region}"
      access_key = "${var.access_key}"
      secret_key = "${var.secret_key}"
    }

    resource "aws_security_group" "test-server-sg" {
      name = "test-server-sg"

      ingress {
        from_port   = 8080
        to_port     = 8080
        protocol    = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
      }
    }

    resource "aws_instance" "test-server" {
      ami           = "${var.ami}"
      instance_type = "${var.instance_type}"

      user_data = <<-EOF
                  #!/bin/bash
                  echo "Hello, World" > index.html
                  nohup busybox httpd -fp 8080 &
                  EOF

      tags {
        name        = "Test Web Server"
        environment = "${var.environment}"
        project     = "${var.project}"
      }
    } 


     variable "region" {
      type        = "string"
      description = "AWS region"
    }

    variable "access_key" {
      type        = "string"
      description = "AWS access key"
    }

    variable "secret_key" {
      type        = "string"
      description = "AWS secret key"
    }

    variable "ami" {
      type        = "string"
      description = "AWS image id"
    }

    variable "instance_type" {
      type        = "string"
      description = "AWS instance type"
    }

    variable "environment" {
      type        = "string"
      description = "AWS environment name"
    }

    variable "project" {
      type        = "string"
      description = "AWS project name"
    }



    output "Test Server Public DNS" {
      value = "${aws_instance.test-server.public_dns}"
    }

    output "Test Server Public IP" {
      value = "${aws_instance.test-server.public_ip}"
    }

    region = "us-east-1"
    access_key = "put your aws access key here"
    secret_key = "put your aws secret key here"
    ami = "ami-40d28157"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    environment = "Test"
    project = "Master Terraform"
```